# Correlation of phrases and answers to them

Tags: modeling, text-mining, methodology

If I ask question in wrong forum, let me know, I'll delete it.  I try find methods, methodology to create predicative model.  Namely, I want to investigate the relationship between the sentences and the answer to them.
For example when person communicate they often say

```
person1:Hi, how are you?
person2:Fine, thank you.
```

I have big dataset with dialogs between people (~100Gb txt files with different dialogs of daily speech)
What method in line of Text Mining can I use to learn that if one person said such a phrase, then on this phrase is usually answered with such a phrase (or a set of words)?